# POST request is not working with .fetch method and HTML forms

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, api, post

extremely new to APIs but I have managed to learn GET, DELETE, PUT and POST requests using postman. However I am trying to do so using HTML now on the front end but I am having difficulty with POST request. I managed to use HTML to implement GET request successfully using the `invokeGET()` method however my method for POST which is `invokePOST()` is not working. I am using HTML forms and I'm not sure if my format is correct or if I am binding to the wrong values, can someone please check and help me, I will appreciate it a lot. I am getting a 400 error and I see that the new object was not added when I submit a GET request. I hope that the backend code I have provided would be sufficient too. Thank you.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employees</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="empid">Employee ID: </label><input type="text" name="empid" id="empid"
                    value="value" placeholder=""/><br/>
                    <label for="name">Name </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                    value="value" placeholder=""/><br/>
                    <label for="age">Age </label><input type="number" name="age" id="age"
                    value="value" placeholder=""/><br/>
                    <label for="email">Email </label><input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                    value="value" placeholder="email"/><br/>
                    <label for="mobile">Mobile </label><input type="number" name="mobile" id="mobile"
                    value="value" placeholder=""/><br/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="invokePOST()">Submit</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="invokeGET()">GET</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function invokeGET() {
        var requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        redirect: 'follow',
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/employee', {requestOptions})
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log("result: " + result))
        .catch((error) => console.log("error: " + error));
        }

        function invokePOST(){
            console.log("this.empid: " + document.getElementById("empid").value );
        const data = {
        "empid": String(document.getElementById("empid").value),
        "name": String(document.getElementById("name").value),
        "age": parseInt(document.getElementById("age").value),
        "email": String(document.getElementById("email").value),
        "mobile": parseInt(document.getElementById("mobile").value)  
        };
        const options = {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json;charset=UTF-8'
        },
        body: (data)
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:8081/employee',options)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((result) => console.log("result: " + result))
        .catch((error) => console.log("error: " + error));;  
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Java backend file:

```
package com.accenture.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

public class Employee {
    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(String empid, String name, int age, String email, String mobile) {
        super();
        this.empid = empid;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String empid;
    
    @Size(min = 2, max = 30, message = "Name must be between 2-30 characters.")
    private String name;
    @Min(value = 18, message = "Age must be greated than 18.")
    @Max(value = 65, message = "Age must be less than 65.")
    private int age;
    @Email(message = "Email format is not correct.")
    private String email;
    private String mobile;
    public String getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }

    public void setEmpid(String empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empid=" + empid + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + ", email=" + email + ", mobile="
                + mobile + "]";
    }

}
```

Error:

```
result: {"timestamp":"2021-07-21T23:52:48.736+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","trace":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.accenture.model.Employee` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.accenture.model.Employee` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:389)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:342)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:185)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:131)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:170)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1063)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:228)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:163)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1723)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.accenture.model.Employee` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1601)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1375)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1322)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:640)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:221)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:197)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:322)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4593)\r\n\tat com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3601)\r\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:378)\r\n\t... 51 more\r\n","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.accenture.model.Employee` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.accenture.model.Employee` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]","path":"/employee"}
```

Comment: You're button is a "submit" button, so it will submit the form. Make it `type=button` instead.

Comment: Instead of inline code like `onclick="invokeGET()"` you should do `document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', invokePOST);` (Note that you should move your script to the end, right before `</body>` or it won't find the form.) This way you can use `function invokePOST(e) {` to be able to access the submission event, then call `e.preventDefault()` on it to stop the browser from submitting the form. Now you can run your AJAX code.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed it to a `type = button` now but I am getting a 400 errror. I think I am having difficulty in binding the values to the right property? @Pointy

Comment: You're passing the string "age" for the `age` property, but the server seems to want that to be a number (it's an `int` in the Java class).

Comment: You aren't reading the form values, just passing literal strings. Provided you followed my advice, you can use `age: Number(this.age.value)` and `name: this.name.value` etc to actually post the form values.

Comment: Thank you all I managed to fix it by using `document.querySelector` and changing data to `JSON.stringify(data)` as it asked for JSON string. Was a silly mistake so I would delete this question soon but I learnt here, thank you